# Why @Secured is not working in Tapestry 5.4.0?

Tags: java, spring-security, tapestry

I just upgraded Tapestry 5.3.8 to 5.4.0, and then I found the @Secured annotation has an issue. If I go to page which has this @Secured, the exception `org/apache/tapestry5/services/TransformMethodSignature` and `could not initialize class nu.localhost.tapestry5.springsecurity.services.internal.TransformConstants2` will thrown (with no detail). Is it no longer supported in 5.4.0? Or do I need to upgrade something in my pom.xml?

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-upload</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-kaptcha</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.got5</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry5-jquery</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.lltyk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-spring-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's working in fine in 5.4.3, are there any other details? Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no stacktrace / detail. I updated my question with how my pom.xml looks like

Comment: It looks like in 5.4.0, `org.apache.tapestry5.services.TransformMethodSignature` is no longer available. If so, what's the replacement?

Comment: I just checked `nu.localhost.tapestry5.springsecurity.services.internal.TransformConstants2` and one of the import classes is `org.apache.tapestry5.services.TransformMethodSignature`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling for days, I'm finally figured out that this library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.lltyk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-spring-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Can not keep up with Tapesty 5.4, because it has a class: `nu.localhost.tapestry5.springsecurity.services.internal.TransformConstants2` that refers to `org.apache.tapestry5.services.TransformMethodSignature` which is not available any longer in Tapestry 5.4.

I've tried to upgrade `tapestry-spring-security` to highest version: 3.0.5, but still can't keep up with Tapestry 5.4, so the only way to solve it, is to remove it. And to replace all the functionalities which was provided by `tapestry-spring-security`, I need to add 4 new libs to pom (in your case you might need to add more or less than 4): `spring-security-core`: 4.0.0.M1, `spring-security-web`: 4.2.3.RELEASE, `spring-dao`: 2.0.8, `servlet-api`: 2.5

In my case, I need to copy the code from the original source for these classes: [LogoutService](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=Tapestry-Spring-Security/src/main/java/nu/localhost/tapestry5/springsecurity/services/LogoutService.java) (interface), [LogoutServiceImpl](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=Tapestry-Spring-Security/src/main/java/nu/localhost/tapestry5/springsecurity/services/internal/LogoutServiceImpl.java), [IfRole](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=Tapestry-Spring-Security/src/main/java/nu/localhost/tapestry5/springsecurity/components/IfRole.java) and [IfLoggedIn](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=Tapestry-Spring-Security/src/main/java/nu/localhost/tapestry5/springsecurity/components/IfLoggedIn.java). Create the files and paste the code.